# kpatch-build failure with Makefile target missing error

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to build a livepatch using kpatch-build insider a Docker container.

So far I am able to see the differences between the original and patched
.o files and creation of new object file.

But create-kpatch-module is not being called and I'm getting an error
indicating "Makefile target missing". I dug through the script, but I'm unable to identify the exact issue.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be wrong? What "Makefile target" is required?

I'm following link at: https://github.com/dynup/kpatch

Upon further inspection:

```
+ /usr/local/libexec/kpatch/create-kpatch-module /home/xyz/.kpatch/tmp/patch/tmp_output.o /home/xyz/.kpatch/tmp/patch/output.o
+ local to_stdout=1
+ [[ 1 -ge 2 ]]
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ tee -a /home/racker/.kpatch/build.log
+ check_pipe_status create-kpatch-module
+ rc=0
+ [[ 0 = 139 ]]
+ cd /home/xyz/.kpatch/tmp/patch
+ logger
+ KPATCH_BUILD=/source/linux
+ KPATCH_NAME=kpatch-4-4-0-2-modules-0-3-2-3-x86_64
+ KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS=/usr/lib/modules/4.4.0+2/extra/kpatch/Module.symvers
+ KPATCH_LDFLAGS=
+ make
```

Comment: I think, it won't hurt to ask such questions in the kpatch mailing list (https://www.redhat.com/mailman/listinfo/kpatch) or to open a bug at https://github.com/dynup/kpatch. The authors usually respond rather quickly there.

Comment: May be unrelated but it caught my attention: the kernel is 4.4.x, but `kpatch-build` calls `create-kpatch-module` and tries to build the patch module in the old 'kpatch' format rather than create a livepatch-compatible patch. Is it what you want? Is CONFIG_LIVEPATCH set in that kernel?

Comment: CONFIG_LIVEPATCH is set. I do need live compatible patch. i am seeing the outcome of differencial object, but not seeing the. ko that&#39;s the result of kpatch-build. this may be the case if sigsegv since i am running within docker but not seeing corefile.

Comment: Minor rewording and reformatting

Comment: Please provide the full command you use to run 'kpatch-build'. I mean, with all options you use, etc.

Comment: As for livepatch support, looks like kpatch-build uses it but calls `create-kpatch-module` for the kernels older than 4.7.0 (except for RHEL kernels) for some reason. https://github.com/dynup/kpatch/blob/4d5febd4a8614ab12416c6717aa3bbc6e16e2edf/kpatch-build/kpatch-build#L654 OK, this explains why `create-kpatch-module` is called rather than `create-klp-module` but it seems unrelated to the main problem discussed here.

Comment: As it is unclear why `make` fails, I could only suggest to run `kpatch-build` with `-d` (other parameters should be the same as before). This is a debug mode. kpatch-build will keep the files it creates then. Then, cd to the directory where it tries to run make and run it manually with the same settings (KPATCH_BUILD, KPATCH_NAME, ...). Then see, how it complains this time, may be that could shed some light. It could be that the sources of the patch module have not been copied there or a broken/incomplete/whatever. But it is just a wild guess.

Comment: kpatch-build -d -n kpatch-4.4.0+2-modules-0.3.2-3.x86_64 -c ./kernel-x86_64.config -s .  -v /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/4.4.0+2/vmlinux meminfo-string2.patch - that is the full command. I have already used -d option and the para I posted in the question is excerpts from -d output. I do have right sources, correct patch and even am generated the patched and orig .o files. It's failing with Make target failure as indicated which seems incorrect.

Comment: Further on code inspection: Here is where it's failing:      if [[ -e "orig/$i" ]]; then
                # create-diff-object orig.o patched.o kernel-object output.o Module.symvers patch-mod-name
                "$TOOLSDIR"/create-diff-object "orig/$i" "patched/$i" "$KOBJFILE" \
                        "output/$i" "$SRCDIR/Module.symvers" "${MODNAME//-/_}" 2>&1 | logger 1
                check_pipe_status create-diff-object